# When and Where to apply logging in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I have a spring-boot application set-upped including logging using log4j. In the application, there are few layers such as `controller, service, models, repositories, exception` etc. At the moment, i have included **ERROR** level logs in the `exception` layer.

```
@Component
public class ExceptionFactory {

    private static final Logger LOG =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionFactory.class);

    public static ApplicationSpecificException create(final Throwable cause, final ExceptionType exceptionType, final Object... messageArguments) {
        LOG.error(MessageFormat.format(exceptionType.getMessage(), messageArguments), cause);
        return new ApplicationSpecificException (exceptionType, cause, messageArguments);
    }

    public static ApplicationSpecificException create(final ExceptionType exceptionType, final Object... messageArguments) {
        LOG.error(MessageFormat.format(exceptionType.getMessage(), messageArguments));
        return new ApplicationSpecificException(exceptionType, messageArguments);
    }
}
```

1. Is it appropriate to use logging in any of the above mentioned layers?
2. Log4j has log level such as **FATAL**, **ERROR**, **WARN**, **INFO**, **DEBUG** and **TRACE** . How to identify the situations to use these level when logging in Spring applications ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the purpose for a separate Exception-Layer. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: I have used a factory make it a cross cutting concern.Find more in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034371/where-to-handle-exceptions-in-spring-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer to your first question:** 
Logging is a so called "cross cutting concern" which means it is not related to the problem domain and so it occurrs everywhere in the code, in every layer.

**Your second question is answered here:** 
[How to determine what log level to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/186844/2507819)